# How to unit test UWP App with Azure Mobile App?

Tags: unit-testing, win-universal-app, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2017

Consider a Visual Studio 2017 solution with 3 projects:

- **UWPApp** - Universal Windows App
- **UWPAppTest** - Universal Windows App Test (NuGet package: Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client)
- **MobileApp** - Azure Mobile App web service (NuGet package: Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server)

I'd like to create a unit test in my **UWPAppTest** project, that calls my web service, running locally in my **MobleApp** web service project.

This requires me to somehow configure Visual Studio to launch the MobileApp project (selecting "don't open a page"). And at the same time, click "Debug Selected Test" in my test explorer. Or, somehow automatically launch the MobileApp in debug mode, when I debug a unit test.

This doesn't look like a supported scenario, and if not, what would be the next best workaround to be able to run a UWP test project, with tests calling a local web service?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

This is something that Azure Mobile Apps has had to deal with as well.  We use end-to-end test scenarios with a mobile backend hosted in the cloud.  The test run will clear the contents of the database prior to each run, thus ensuring the appropriate unit testing.  The biggest thing here is dealing with state.

In a local debug version, you will want to set the URI passed into the MobileServicesClient to your localhost, but things should not be any different.  Just ensure you are fixing the starting point and ending point of your database for each test.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I get what you're saying, but I think you're one step ahead of me. My challenge is that I configure Visual Studio to "Start" **both** my UWP Unit Test app AND my Service (MobileApp). However when I right-click a unit test, and select "Debug Selected Tests", the test function begins to run (UWP test app launches), however IISExpress never starts, and therefore my call to my [local] web service fails. Does this help clarify?

Comment: Yep - what I was really telling you is that you can't do what you need to do here.